# How I can integrate my app with Firebase Crashlytics? Problems with dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, google-play-services, crashlytics

I have problems with my dependencies, but I did all things from this guide. And also try to remove dependencies with "exclude" and "useVersion" in Gradle app file.

Build log (You can see dublicated classes from firebase and google-play-services libraries):

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$ConditionalUserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Event found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$EventInterceptor found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Param found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$UserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Param found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.4.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$UserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.4.1)
```

My app level Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

   ...

    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "${rootDir}/libs", include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.4'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.6'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.1.6'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.6'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:6.1.6'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:6.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"
    //Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesLatestVersion"
    // Koin for Android
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koinVersion"

    // Koin Android Scope features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-scope:$koinVersion"
    // Koin Android ViewModel features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:$koinVersion"
    // Koin Android Experimental features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-ext:$koinVersion"


    implementation project(path: ':data')
    implementation project(path: ':domain')
    implementation project(path: ':maplayoutlib')

    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
}
```

And my project level Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    ext.coroutinesLatestVersion = '1.3.3'
    ext.koinVersion = '2.1.5'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I hope that you can help me

**EDIT:**

Firstly I have the same dependency problem, when add

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
```

with 
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

I solve this problem by using v12.0.1

```
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
            details.useVersion '12.0.1'
        }
        if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
            details.useVersion '12.0.1'
        }
    }
```

It was working before I add dependency on crashlytics

```
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    ...

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
```

You can see this version of my gradle files upper

Comment: Show me dependecies of maplayoutlib you using google map right? It should be update dependency too

Comment: I use osmdroid. All my map dependencies exist in app level Gradle file. You can see them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Crashlytics should start working from the second you add it to the project. No other implementation is needed.
Your gradle files looks fine to me, but try changing the first line in app-level Gradle file to this:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

and updating crashlytics dependency in project-level Gradle file to v2.1.1

`classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I use mavlink.jar in my modules. And that's why I replace libs folder in rootDir with my mavlink.jar.

I try to build project with different dependency lib versions. I already change crashlytics dependency ```classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.0'```, but I have the same result with duplicated classes. I don't know why